# No puedo enviar pdf generado con dompdf usando la libreria phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, dompdf

el pdf es generado de forma correcta pero no logro enviar el pdf adjunto ha un destinatario tengo problemas saludos.

mi código

```
ob_start();

     //aquí va mi código html para general la estructura pdf

<?php require_once ("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
          require_once ("PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
          // inicio de php Mailer

                        // creo el objeto phpmailer
              $mail = new PHPMailer();
              // asigno el envío por SMTP mucho más rápido y fiable
              $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
              // mi servidor requiere autentificación
              $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
              // utilizo constantes almacenadas fuera del script para darle más seguridad a los datos, aparte de así poder reutilizar los mismos

              $mail->Username = "TLS";
              $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
              $mail->Password = "xxxxx";
              $mail->From = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
              $mail->FromName = "equipos";

              // aumentar el timeout es recomendable si estas en un hosting gratuito
              $mail->Timeout=30;
              // creo el objeto DOMPDF

          // final de php mailer
    // use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    $dompdf= new DOMPDF();
      $dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
        $dompdf->render();
        $pdf=$dompdf->output();
        $filename= $f['cod_cotizacion'].'-'.$f['nombreEmpresa'].'.pdf';
        $dompdf->stream($filename,array("Attachment"=> 0));
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4','landscape');

          // inicia phpmailer
          if (!$gestor = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
                echo "No se puede abrir el archivo ($filename)";
                exit;
                }
                if (fwrite($gestor, $pdf) === FALSE) {
                echo "No se puede escribir al archivo ($filename)";
                exit;
                }
                echo "Éxito, se escribió al archivo ($filename)";
                fclose($gestor);

                // las siguientes 2 lineas son imprescindibles si envias varios correos a la vez, por ejemplo dentro de un bucle while, así garantizas que solo se envíe este fichero al recipiente de correo destinatario

                $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
                $mail->ClearAttachments();

                // añado el usuario de destino y otras configuraciones

                $mail->AddAddress("gabo2cuau@gmail.com","Gabriel");
                $mail->Subject = "Prueba de phpmailer";
                $mail->Body = $dompdf;

                // nombre_adjunto es el nombre que verá el usuario cuando reciba el mail como nombre del archivo
                $mail->AddAttachment($filename,"Cotizacion.pdf");
                // texto alternativo por si el usuario no admite html

                $mail->AltBody = "Mensaje de prueba mandado con phpmailer en formato solo texto";
                $exito = $mail->Send();

                // borro el fichero real

                unlink($filename);
                if(!$exito){
                echo "Problemas enviando correo electrónico";
                echo "
                ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
                }
                else
                echo "Mensaje enviado correctamente";

          // terminaphpMailer



    ?>
```

Comment: Hola, por seguridad no se deben poner usuarios y passwords. Ya te lo he enmascarado.

Comment: Deberías añadir si recibes un error. Mira los logs del servidor a ver si te está poniendo algo. Si no te pone nada, pero no recibes el correo, lo mas seguro es que tu correo se esté catalogando como spam y el servidor lo esté bloqueando. Quizá debas poner el puerto de salida del smtp, que al tener tls no será el 25 si no el 587 para hotmail. Por otro lado, según microsoft, necesitas si o si un cliente desde el que enviarlos. Revisa los logs y actualiza la pregunta con los resultados. Un saludo.

Comment: Coincido con JDev en la cuestión de las contraseñas. De hecho, el problema es que aunque su edición quite la contraseña de la pregunta, se seguirá pudiendo ver en el historial de ediciones de la pregunta. Te recomiendo que A) cambies la contraseña inmediatamente y B)borres la pregunta y la vuelvas a postear, eliminando los datos identificativos.

Comment: Nunca he tenido ese error. Prueba a reiniciar el pc, a veces funciona.

Comment: Prueba añadiendo la ruta de la siguiente manera: `$mail->addAttachment('ruta-del-pdf/'.$filename);`